# Convert certain file types within all subdirectories with dos2unix

Tags: shell-script

I have thousands of files I need convert to Linux standard line ending format, i.e. using `dos2unix`.

The files to convert have extension either `.cpp` or `.h`

The files in question are structured in subdirectories.

I know I could find all files all with:

```
find ./ -follow -type f \( -iname \*.cpp -o -iname \*.h \)
```

But how do I apply the command to them?

I suppose with a simple `bash` script with some `for` cycle, which I fail to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use.

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*.cpp" -o -iname "*.h" \) -exec dos2unix {} +
```

Comment: `+` instead of `;`  that's a new feature to me - and one less reason to prefer xargs.